# JMeter - Response time keeps increasing

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for load testing. I have noticed that the response time it shows keeps increasing until the test plan has finished running.

I have 3 thread groups with the following settings:
Number of threads: 900, 180, 180
Rampup: 0
Loop count: 20

Each of the threads has a constant throughput controller with the following settings:
Throughput: 900, 180, 180

[Jmeter Test Plan http://cl.ly/UPhC/jmeter_test_plan.png](http://cl.ly/UPhC/jmeter_test_plan.png)

I don't understand why the response time keeps increasing from the beginning until the end of the test plan execution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the system under test is creating objects and provoking garbage collections. That won't be a problem at first, but will get worst as the test progresses. Do a profiling of the JVM of the system under test with [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be the target system.
But if you are running your plan in GUI mode then it can explain your issue particularly View Results Tree listener which exists for DEBUGGING Test plan and absolutely not for GUI Load Test.

Read this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

So fix is:
- Run your test in NON GUI mode and keep only Summary report

You can after test reload result file.
You may also see this:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/